# Substitute string in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, bioinformatics

I have a `pandas.DataFrame` that contains the boolean rules that say if an enzyme is expressed or not. Some rules are simple (expression depends on 1 gene), some others are more complex (expression depends on several genes)

```
>>gprs.head()

Out[362]: 
        Rxn                             rule
0     13DAMPPOX      HGNC:549 or HGNC:550 or HGNC:80
6  24_25VITD2Hm      HGNC:2602
8     25VITD2Hm      HGNC:16354 or (HGNC:249 and HGNC:250) or (HGNC:249 and HGNC:251) or (HGNC:250 and HGNC:251) or HGNC:252 or HGNC:253 or HGNC:255 or HGNC:256

...
```

A dict object contains the info about gene expression: (1=expr, 0=not expr)

```
>>translation

'HGNC:80':1
'HGNC:2602':0
 etc...
```

I want to replace the expression info contained in the 'translation' object into my 'gprs' `pandas.DataFrame`. So far I have:

```
for index, row in gprs.iterrows():
    row['rule']=row['rule'].replace(r'(', "")
    row['rule']=row['rule'].replace(r')', "")
    ruleGenes=re.split(" and | or ",(row['rule']))
    for gene in ruleGenes:
        if re.match("HGNC:HGNC:", gene):
            gene=gene[5:]
            try:
               gprs=gprs.replace(gene,translation[gene])
            except:
               print 'error in ', gene
        else:
            try:
                gprs=gprs.replace(gene,translation[gene])
            except:
                print 'error in ', gene
```

This works only when the rule is simple (1 element) but fails with more complex rules:

```
>>gprs.head()

0     13DAMPPOX  HGNC:549 or HGNC:550 or HGNC:80
6  24_25VITD2Hm                                0
7  24_25VITD3Hm  HGNC:16354 or (HGNC:249 and HGNC:250) or (HGNC:249 and HGNC:251) or (HGNC:250 and HGNC:251) or HGNC:252 or HGNC:253 or HGNC:255 or HGNC:256
```

Eventually I want to substitute 'or' with the max() function, 'and' with the min() function and evaluate the boolean rules.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:

when using EFT's code, there are issues when one string is substring of another i.e: 'HGNC:54' and 'HGNC:549'

```
>>translation

'HGNC:54':0
'HGNC:549':1
```

results in:

```
>>gprs.head(1)

         Rxn                             rule                  translation 
0     13DAMPPOX       HGNC:549 or HGNC:550 or HGNC:80         09 or 1 or 0
```

How should I do to substitute only the entire string and not the substrings?

EDIT EDIT:

It works with:

```
for_eval = {k+'(?![0-9])' : str(v) for k, v in translation.items()}
gprs['translation'] = gprs['rule'].replace(for_eval, regex=True)
```

Thanks EFT for the suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entering the translation can be accomplished with

```
>>>for_eval = {k+'(?![0-9])': str(v) for k, v in translation.items()}
>>>gprs['translation'] = gprs['rule'].replace(for_eval, regex=True)
```

**Explanation:**

The first line of this

```
>>>for_eval = {k+'(?![0-9])': str(v) for k, v in translation.items()}
```

swaps `0` and `1` for their string forms, `'0'` and `'1'`, respectively, in preparation for inserting them into the string in the second line. Adding '(?![0-9])' to the key checks for and ignores matches where there are more digits to follow, avoiding a match on only the first part of a key.

The second line

```
>>>gprs['translation'] = gprs['rule'].replace(for_eval, regex=True)
```

performs the replacement as a column operation in pandas, rather than iterating over each row in python, which for larger data sets, say 30 or more entries in this case, is much slower.

Without `regex=True`, this would only work on an exact match, giving the same issue you experienced when trying to implement longer rules.

Example, with credit to u/Stephen Rauch for test cases:

```
In [3]:translation = {
    'HGNC:80': 1,
    'HGNC:249': 1,
    'HGNC:250': 1,
    'HGNC:251': 0,
    'HGNC:252': 1,
    'HGNC:253': 0,
    'HGNC:255': 1,
    'HGNC:256': 1,
    'HGNC:549': 0,
    'HGNC:550': 1,
    'HGNC:2602': 0,
    'HGNC:16354': 1,
}

In [4]:gprs = pd.DataFrame([
    ('HGNC:550', 1),
    ('HGNC:2602', 0),
    ('HGNC:253 or HGNC:549', 0),
    ('HGNC:549 or HGNC:550 or HGNC:80', 1),
    ('HGNC:549 or (HGNC:550 and HGNC:2602)', 0),
    ('HGNC:549 or (HGNC:550 and HGNC:16354)', 1),
    ('HGNC:16354 or (HGNC:249 and HGNC:250) or (HGNC:249 and HGNC:251)', 1)
], columns = ['rule', 'target'])

In [5]:for_eval = {k: str(v) for k, v in translation.items()}

In [6]:gprs['translation'] = gprs['rule'].replace(for_eval, regex=True)

In [7]:gprs['translation']

Out[7]:
0                              1
1                              0
2                         0 or 0
3                    0 or 1 or 1
4                 0 or (1 and 0)
5                 0 or (1 and 1)
6    1 or (1 and 1) or (1 and 0)
Name: translation, dtype: object
```

For the second part that you're looking at later, `eval`, as mentioned and elaborated on in u/Stephen Rauch's answer, can be used to evaluate the expression contained in the string produced. To do so, `pd.Series.map` can be used to apply element-wise operations on a series more quickly than by using `iterrows`. Here, that would look like this

```
In [10]:gprs['translation'].map(eval)
Out[10]: 
0    1
1    0
2    0
3    1
4    0
5    1
6    1
Name: translation, dtype: int64
```

Alternatively, if trying to eke out every last bit of performance to be had, using regex pattern-matching on the outputs instead of map is an option. It becomes more dependent on specifically how your rules are phrased, but if they're all as nicely formatted as the three in your post, "and"s all pairwise and parenthesized, no nesting, then

```
# set any 'and' term with a zero in it to zero
>>>ands = gprs['translation'].str.replace('0 and \d|\d and 0', '0')
# if any ones remain, only 'or's and '1 and 1' statements are left
>>>ors = ands.replace('1', 1, regex=True)
# faster to force it to numeric than to search the remaining terms for zeros
>>>out = pd.to_numeric(ors, errors='coerce').fillna(0)
>>>out
0    1.0
1    0.0
2    0.0
3    1.0
4    0.0
5    1.0
6    1.0
Name: translation, dtype: float64
```

should be around five times faster, checked using the timeit module, for more than a few thousand rows, with the breakeven point around 60 or 70 entries.

Comment: Thank you crediting me with the test cases, but the actual insight, as you discovered when your first answer did not work, was using eval to do the conversion.  So if you are going to give credit..  Thanks again.

Comment: @Stephen You were certainly the first to use `eval` in your answer, and I don't mean to take away from that; I sincerely didn't notice or consider the presence of the same built-in in our submissions. For clarity, though, the error in my submission for which I temporarily deleted my post was my failure to convert the values of the translation dictionary to strings before running replace. This meant the rules were overwritten in full with the first value whose key was matched, which, by some unhappy quirk of dictionary ordering, happened to output correct answers for the example I considered.

Comment: You original submission did not contain `eval`.  Before you deleted it, I tried to replicate your result because I thought you had discovered some deep panda's magic.  So 3+ hours later you re-posted with eval.  Which is cool since you brought it into pandas for which the OP may be grateful, but my original statement about the insight in the solution ...  Look, I have no desire be acrimonious here, in general the people around here answering pandas questions are very collegial, and I do not want to disturb that. So I will sign off. Cheers.

Comment: I also don’t want to disturb that, & I am sorry for perhaps having been a bit prickly in my last comment. I suppose what bothered me was what felt like an implication that I had been stuck on, & then cribbed, the use of a built-in function I didn’t think twice about. If it helps, the post had no `.map(eval)` because my error resulted in a function that returned an `int` (a Series of them anyway). Why eval an int?
Looking over your post, I do see explanation of & elaboration on the use of `eval` which I do not provide. I will happily edit my post to direct the reader seeking explanation there.

Comment: Thanks for getting back.  You are new here, and I think your eventual post was excellent.  It is just that, derivative or not, it was a very similar in  concept to what I had proposed, and came quite some time after my post. So, as a general etiquette thing, at least for most that I have watched doing pandas/numpy posts, most will acknowledge those that came before, and then go on and blow them out the water with a even better contribution.  So, once again, thanks for getting back, Welcome to Stackoverflow!, and I hope you have fun here....  Also, hoping to see you around.

Comment: thank you both for your answers, @u/EFT, your approach is working correctly, but I have some problems when a string is a substring of another one : i.e.  'HGNC:214' and 'HGNC: 21487'. please check the EDIT in the top post for details.

Comment: I'll edit once I've had the chance to confirm this works and doesn't give rise to any other issues, but changing the dictionary comprehension to {k+'(?![0-9])': str(v) for k, v in translation.items()} should address this. '(?![0-9])' in a regex says to match a substring only if the next character isn't a digit in [0-9]. Since this is already being used with regex matching, that should do it, though I want to check end of string behavior, to be sure it accepts substrings with no next character.

Comment: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: it works with: {str(k)+'(?![0-9])': str(v) for k, v in translation.items()},  thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @Ndr That TypeError suggests some of your keys are just integers, not strings with that 'HGNC:' bit in front – if those keys are being matched to genes with that prefix in the rules, that can produce broken or inaccurate evaluation as things stand. e.g. something like `(1 and HGNC:0) or (1 and 0)`, which will give a syntax error with `eval` or a one instead of the zero it with the regex.

Comment: you're right , a '0' key slipped in somewhere... once deleted it solved the error

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method that can be used to calculate whether the enzyme is expressed.

#### Code:

```
import re
RE_GENE_NAME = re.compile(r'(HGNC:[0-9]+)')

def calc_expressed(translation_table, rule_str):
    rule_expr = RE_GENE_NAME.sub(r'translation_table["\1"]', rule_str)
    return eval(rule_expr)
```

**How does it work?**

The idea here it to take a rule like:

```
HGNC:253 or HGNC:549
```

And change it into:

```
translation_table["HGNC:253"] or translation_table["HGNC:549"]
```

**IE:** change all instance of values like `HGNC:1234` to `translation_table["HGNC:1234"]`.

This results in a string which is a legal python expression.  The resulting expression can be evaluated with `eval()`.

#### Test Code:

```
translation = {
    'HGNC:80': 1,
    'HGNC:249': 1,
    'HGNC:250': 1,
    'HGNC:251': 0,
    'HGNC:252': 1,
    'HGNC:253': 0,
    'HGNC:255': 1,
    'HGNC:256': 1,
    'HGNC:549': 0,
    'HGNC:550': 1,
    'HGNC:2602': 0,
    'HGNC:16354': 1,
}

test_rules = (
    ('HGNC:550', 1),
    ('HGNC:2602', 0),
    ('HGNC:253 or HGNC:549', 0),
    ('HGNC:549 or HGNC:550 or HGNC:80', 1),
    ('HGNC:549 or (HGNC:550 and HGNC:2602)', 0),
    ('HGNC:549 or (HGNC:550 and HGNC:16354)', 1),
    ('HGNC:16354 or (HGNC:249 and HGNC:250) or (HGNC:249 and HGNC:251)', 1)
)

for rule, expected in test_rules:
    assert expected == calc_expressed(translation, rule)
```